# Web Platform Installer: Windows Cache Extension 2.0 for PHP 7.4 failed to install

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, web-platform-installer, wincache

If you try and install PHP 7.4 via Microsoft Web Platform Installer on Windows Server 2012, it installs the core PHP component but fails to install winCache and PHP manager.

I was able to install the PHP manager via a separate MSI. However, i cannot find an MSI for the wincache extension. If one tries to install the component via Web PI, the following error is thrown:
[image]

And if one tries to download the extension on its own via the official IIS website (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/wincache-extension) it instead redirects to an unrelated page.

Is it simply not possible to install PHP via Web Platform Installer anymore? The products have been listed since the 31st of January 2020 though the downloads seem to be broken now for months...

Comment: Same problem on Windows Server 2019. PHP v7.3.13 is the last one that works although even that fails to install the PHP Manager. PHP Manager v1.5.0 can be manually installed afterwards and all is well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you view the Wep Platform installer log. Then you will see this.

```
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : HttpWebRequest failure while trying to retrieve filename from fwlink http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincache/files/wincache-2.0.0/wincachewpi-2.0.0.8-7.4-nts-vc15-x64.exe/download. Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

So that means the source link of Windows Cache Extension 2.0 for PHP 7.4 has been corrupted for a period of time.

When I access sourceforge.net to download the extension. I also notice that the link has been changed to

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/wincache/files/development/wincache-2.0.0.8-dev-7.4-nts-vc15-x64.exe/download
```

So you can either download the extension here manually.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/wincache/

or post this issue to their vendor forum to ask PG to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure WinCache is released yet for PHP v7.4. They appear to be still asking for feedback: [PHP 7.4 feedback](https://forums.iis.net/t/1249312.aspx?PHP%207%204%20feedback)

The latest release version I can find is wincachewpi-2.0.0.8-7.3-nts-vc15-x64 and this installs fine from **Web Platform Installer**. I'd suggest sticking with PHP v7.3.13 unless there is a compelling reason for PHP 7.4.x.

NOTE: PHP Manager fails to install with **Web Platform Installer** when installing PHP v7.3.13 but not a showstopper as PHP Manager v1.5.0 can be manually installed afterwards.